# Getting wrong count when selecting tr of each table tbody

Tags: jquery

I have multiple tables in my view, and I would like to get the count of all the `tr`s that are in the `tbody` of each `table`.

### My `table`s look like this:

```
<table id="Table-One" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Header One</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Header Two</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in list)
        {
            <tr class="text-center text-dark">
                <td>Testing</td>
                <td>Testing</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="text-danger js-delete" data-pic-id="@Model.Id" data-pic-fk-id="@item.ForeignKeyId">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Here is my <del>jQuery</del> JS:

```
var myTable = $("#Table-One");

var countAllTablesRows = $("table tbody tr").length;
console.log(countAllTablesRows); // gives correct # of 8 on page load

myTable.on("click",
    ".js-delete",
    function() {
        var link = $(this);
        var row = $(this).parents("tr");

        var countAllTablesRowsInsideMethod = $("table tbody tr").length;

        console.log(countAllTablesRowsInsideMethod); // gives incorrect # of 13 on click of the link
    });
```

This is resulting in **`13`**, which when I count is including the rows that are in each of the table's `thead` elements. The number should be **`8`**. How do I get this to not include the rows that are in the `thead` element?

I figured I didn't have to do use `.each` because that query should get all table elements, right?

**UPDATE**

After logging the rows on click of the link I am looking at the extra 5 rows being generated, and they all have innerHTML that looks like this:

```
"<td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_other_month xdsoft_weekend" data-year="2017" data-month="11" data-date="31"><div>31</div></td><td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" data-year="2018" data-month="0" data-date="1"><div>1</div></td><td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" data-year="2018" data-month="0" data-date="2"><div>2</div></td><td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" data-year="2018" data-month="0" data-date="3"><div>3</div></td><td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date" data-year="2018" data-month="0" data-date="4"><div>4</div></td><td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date" data-year="2018" data-month="0" data-date="5"><div>5</div></td><td title="" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" data-year="2018" data-month="0" data-date="6"><div>6</div></td>"
```

I have no idea where those are being generated from.

Comment: Umm... shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan edited.. my `tbody` is inside a `foreach` loop.  I have multiple tables that look exactly the same as the one I posted.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vng44Lvo/ this shows the correct number, what version of jquery are you using? Also what browser are you using? Can you attach the generated code instead of the loop. Are you sure there isn't other tables on the page?

Comment: @Huangism There are multiple tables on the same page.

Comment: @GTown-Coder well `$("table tbody tr")` would count all of the tables on the page with tbody's tr so you might want to check that out, if you just want this table, use the ID like sumit suggested in his answer

Comment: @GTown-Coder Still works with multiple tables: https://jsfiddle.net/vng44Lvo/2/

Comment: @GTown-Coder There is probably a table that you are not counting and just did not see to give you the inflated number but the jquery code is doing what it is supposed to do

Comment: @Huangism I've edited my question to be more specific with my table and jQuery. I got it to work, but don't why the first method wasn't working

Comment: The only difference there is when the statements are executed. There must be tables or rows getting added that you aren't thinking of. Try logging the 13 rows and seeing what is present that you don't expect.

Comment: Your whole question is far too much code. all you had to show us was this specific line: `$("table tbody tr").length`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your code, and it's still logging the same count. Rest assured it's not that code that's causing the problem. I have the feeling there's more to that click event handler than what you've shown, that perhaps is throwing off your count. Feel free to copy the Stack Snippet from my answer and add your own (rendered)HTML and JavaScript to prove it to yourself.

Comment: @JasonP check my update.

Comment: @JasonP I have looked that up and it reference jQuery datetimepicker which I am also using on the same page but not in any of my tables.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan check my update

Comment: @vsync check my update.

Comment: Well, if it's on the same page, `$("table tbody tr")` is going to pick it up, since it looks for all `table` elements on the page. If you want to narrow the focus, specify an element that wraps all of the tables you care about as the second arg `$("table tbody tr", element)`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry for my confusion, but I have a textbox that uses the datetimepicker plugin that's in a separate form.. not in a table, so how is my jQuery picking that up?

Comment: Your plugin likely generates a `table` with a `tbody` with at least one `tr` in it, in preparation for displaying the calendar. jQuery searches the entire DOM, so it will find that, as long as it exists under the same `html` element.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ahh gotcha, yeah I just added a class to all of my `tbody` elements and changed my jQuery to `var countAllTablesRowsInsideMethod = $("table tbody.pic-tbody tr").length;` and it gave the right #!

Comment: Please see my answer which address this question in a much broader way which can actually help others who come to this thread rather than solving the very specific issue that you alone faced and probably nobody else will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here was a hidden table generated by a datetimepicker plugin. The OP solved that by adding classes to the desired `tbody` elements, which let them identify those in the selector.

What remains below was an ongoing attempt to show that the code as stated was working.

---

Works on my box. When I run the following code in Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10, it logs 2, which I would expect with this HTML... Works in Firefox 58. Even works with Edge. Heck, it even works in IE11!

```js
$(function() {
  var myTable = $("#Table-One");

  var countAllTablesRows = $("table tbody tr").length;
  console.log(countAllTablesRows); // gives correct # of 8

  myTable.on("click",
    ".js-delete",
    function(e) {
      var link = $(this);
      var row = $(this).parents("tr");

      var countAllTablesRowsInsideMethod = $("table tbody tr").length;

      console.log(countAllTablesRowsInsideMethod); // gives incorrect # of 13
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table-One" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">
        Header One
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">
        Header Two
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center text-dark">
      <td>
        Testing
      </td>
      <td>
        Testing
      </td>
      <td><a href="" class="js-delete">Testing</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="Table-Two" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">
        Header One
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">
        Header Two
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center text-dark">
      <td>
        Testing
      </td>
      <td>
        Testing
      </td>
      <td>Testing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I responded to your comment and edited my question to reflect the `foreach` statement inside my `tbody`

Comment: It doesn't matter. The point is that it's not logging 2, which it would if it were counting the row in the `thead` element.

Comment: Shouldn't this "there is nothing wrong with your jquery" be a comment instead of an answer. Most likely there are more tables on the page and the number is wrong but who knows

Comment: You can with jsfiddle

Comment: Feel free to downvote if you don't find it useful. Or flag it if you feel it is of very low quality. I don't think I need to tell you that @Huangism...

Comment: I am only suggesting to ask more questions before answering when things are not that clear. You know this answer is not really an answer, I don't like downvoting unless the answer is just plain wrong. I am hoping the OP will provide more info or code so you can eventually update your answer

Comment: Even though we finally figured this out through me slowly updating my question so that you're more clear, I really appreciate your help.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, no worries. I was actually going to suggest deleting the question, since it seems unlikely anyone else will get into this exact situation again.

Answer (score 1):

### Count in the demo below shows `3` rows, as expected.

This suggest you are mistaken in your manual count of rows. maybe there are some hidden ones. check with the browser's inspector.

There **has** to be something going on somewhere else in your code when you're clicking that `delete` button and there's simply not enough information in your question. Also, this is an extremely specific scenario and probably it's a human mistake of design.

```js
var tBodyRowsCount = $("table tbody tr").length;

console.log("Rows in tBody: ", tBodyRowsCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### It's *safest* to make your selector more specific:

```
$(".myTable > tbody > tr") // where ".myTable" is a specific <table> element
```

This will eliminate any unknown or unwanted table rows which might be inside nested tables which are themselves inside the top-most table rows.